# C++ function parameters wont compile

Tags: c++, function-pointers, function-parameter

So I have a function with the prototype

```
double Solution::bisect
(
    double xLeft,
    double xRight,
    double epsilon,
    double f(double x, EquCoeffs coeffsStruct),
    bool &error
);
```

where function `f` is prototyped like this

```
double Solution::f(double x, EquCoeffs coeffsStruct);
```

The error I am getting in Visual Studio is `argument of type "double(Solution::*)(double x, Solution::EquCoeffs coeffsStruct)" is incompatible with parameter of type "double(*)(double x, Solution::EquCoeffs coeffsStruct)"`

which occurs when I try to call `bisect(xLeft, xRight, epsilon, f, error);`
where `xRight` `xLeft` `epsilon`, are type `double` and `error` is type `bool`.

Why won't this compile? I'm not sure I understand the error. How is a `double(Solution::*)` different than `double(*)`?

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. The error is from how you call the function. You try to call it with a pointer to a member function while it expects a pointer to a free function

Comment: How can I make it expect a pointer to a member function instead?

Comment: ...btw the error already tells you all you need to know ;)

Comment: Okay, but when I change the signature of the function to expect `Solution::f`, I get `qualified name is not allowed`. I did some googling, and apparently I am not allowed to specify a class name here? What gives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function pointers can be tedious to work with, this is where `typedef`s come in handy:

```
typdef R (*FREE_FUNC)(ARGS);
```

makes `FREE_FUNC` an alias for function pointers of type `R(*)(ARGS)`, ie functions with `ARGS` parameter and `R` return type. It may look a bit strange, that the new name appears in the middle on the typdef. However, everywhere else using function pointers is then much nicer, for example

```
typedef void (*LOGGER)(R,ARGS);
R decorate(FREE_FUNC func,LOGGER logger,ARGS args){
    R result = func(args);
    logger(result,args);
    return result;
}
```

Member function pointers are different, because you need an object to call them:

```
struct Foo {
    void foo(){std::cout << "moo \n";}
    void moo(){std::cout << "xyz \n";}
};

typedef void (Foo::*FOO_MEMBER_FUNC)();

void fooCaller(Foo f,FOO_MEMBER_FUNC mf){
    (f.*mf)();
    // ... or ...
    Foo* f_ptr = &f;
    (f_ptr->*mf)();
}

int main() {
    FOO_MEMBER_FUNC foo_ptr = &Foo::foo;
    FOO_MEMBER_FUNC moo_ptr = &Foo::moo;
    Foo f;
    fooCaller(f,foo_ptr);
    fooCaller(f,moo_ptr);
}
```

I should also mention, that there are better ways to pass functions. You can take a look at [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function).

Comment: I'm aware; unfortunately, my requirements dictate that I do it by passing a function parameter in such a manner.

Comment: @Airhead not sure if I understand you. If the answer didnt help, you need to provide the code ([mcve])

Comment: My solution ended up being just to use a free function instead. Thanks though!